# How do I remove text and switch place of comma and period in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, substitution

I'm trying to convert this text: `$ 12,345.67 USD` into `12.345,67`. So, remove everything but digits and comma/period but reverse comma/period.

I currently have this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(B222;"[^\d\.]+";);".";",")
```

This removes the text and the period, and then substitutes the comma with a period. The issue us that it leaves me with 12345,67 without the period and I'd like to see if I can get the right format for the number, even though it works as is.

Comment: Make sure to escape the character in case of regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(B222;"^\D+|\D+$"; ""); ",(\d+)\."; ".$1,")
```

**Details**

- `REGEXREPLACE(...;"^\D+|\D+$"; "")` will remove all non-digit chars at the start and end of the string, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RKDKdR/2)
- `REGEXREPLACE(...;",(\d+)\."; ".$1,")` will swap `,` and `.` around the number. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RKDKdR/1).

Comment: That works if I replace the comma here ", "" with a semicolon "; "". Thank you very much

Comment: @RasmusEsbensen It is because I am using a comma to separate arguments, sorry for that, I think I have fixed it.